# What is Snaplogic?

Tags: etl, paas, data-integration, snaplogic

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SnapLogic):

> SnapLogic is a commercial software company that provides Integration Platform as a Service (iPaaS) tools for connecting Cloud data sources, SaaS applications and on-premises business software applications.

It is surely a competitor to [informatica](/questions/tagged/informatica), but it doesn't seem to be just another ETL tool. I have a rough understanding that it is used for data integration but that's about it.

Is it merely an ETL tool or does it have any other functionality? Also, what are iPaaS tools in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the best place to learn about SnapLogic will be their website, https://www.snaplogic.com/

Here is a video of SnapLogic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYJK7bjOlA0

A simple developer friendly example:
Let's say i want to search for twitter feeds posted with a particular hashtag by a particular person and write that data into a database of my choice or into amazon S3. SnapLogic allows me to do that without learning about the Twitter API and AWS. SnapLogic takes care of the abstraction for the user so that they can focus on the business logic of things.

The demos are available in the blog: http://www.snaplogic.com/blog

A look at SnapLogic on crunchbase is not a bad idea and you could also find their competitors there.

Your other questions like what are integration platform as a service(iPaaS) tools is too basic and should just be googled.
Basically there are two types of cloud integration, iPaaS and dPaaS

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's been a long time since I posted this question and due to the apparent lack of response, I had to figure things out myself. Although, I was aware of their site and documentation (which is kinda limited), I wanted to understand the scope of its use (I have a fair understanding now). On an unrelated note, StackOverflow needs a SnapLogic tag.

Comment: Glad it helped. I was about to create a tag for SnapLogic.

Comment: Is Snaplogic worth learning for a Microsoft MVC developer with BizTalk experience??

Comment: Well, SnapLogic has snaps (connectors) for several Microsoft products like: Dynamics 365 (aka Dynamics CRM), Dynamics 365 for Operations (aka Dynamics AX), Azure SQL and Microsoft Office. It definitely is good to learn and it will be complementary to your data integration experience with BizTalk. On a side note, Microsoft did fund SnapLogic in 2016: https://www.onmsft.com/news/microsoft-part-37-5-million-investment-snaplogic

Answer (score 2):

Basically SnapLogic is a ***iPaas Tool (Integration Platforma as a Service)***, One of the growing online cloud based integration ETL tool.

As per the Gartner report one of leader in "Enterprise Integration Platform as a Service" refer below link

https://www.snaplogic.com/press-releases/gartner-names-snaplogic-as-a-leader-in-the-magic-quadrant

About tool and few useful links,

**1.Designer**

It's a canvas area to play and develop your integration pipelines.

**2.Manager**

Is is a main important to manage all the projects , pipelines, assets ,accounts,creating users and providing permissions, and also import and export of 
projects.

**3.Dashboard**

Monitoring the pipelines logs and information of running pipelines and history.

**Useful links:**

1.Main site:
https://www.snaplogic.com

2.SnapLogic free trial:
https://www.snaplogic.com/free-trial

3.SnapLogic Documentation
http://doc.snaplogic.com/

4.SnapLogic Community
https://community.snaplogic.com/

5.SnapLogic Blog
https://www.snaplogic.com/blog

Also recently they released SnapLogic Extremem, Please have a look

https://www.snaplogic.com/press-releases/introducing-snaplogic-extreme-to-help-data-engineers-operationalize-cloud-based-big-data-integrations